# Handling Json response with alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I'm working on a IOS login application , but I don't know how to handle the Json response from the server , I want to write a Boolean function that depends on the server response :
this is the server response if the username and the password are right :

```
SUCCESS: {
    users =     (
                {
            email = test;
            id = 1;
            money = 200;
            password = test;
            username = test;
        }
    );
}
```

And if the username and password are wrong :

```
SUCCESS: {
    users =     (
    );
}
```

this is my backend code written in NodeJs:

```
app.get('/login/:username/:password',(req,res)=>{
    let user = req.params;
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM  users WHERE username = ? And password = ? ";
    mysqlConnection.query(sql,[user.username,user.password],
    function(err, rows){
        if(!err){    

       res.send(JSON.stringify({"users" : rows}));
}
 else {
console.log(err)
         }
    }
```

This is my swift function :

```
   class func login(username : String , password : String, _ completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        let url = "http://127.0.0.1:3000/login/"+username+"/"+password
        Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON{response in
            switch response.result
            {
            case .failure:
    print(response)
    completion(false)
            case .success:
                //I want to handle the response here
                //return true if the username and password are right
                //return wrong if not
    print(response)
    completion(true)

            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Im working on an academic project so im forced to use alamofire and swiftyJson

Comment: thank you for the advice but we can't use any other library even if it is a warper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use above code:-

```
func CallAPI(){

    let parameters: [String: Any] = [
        "Username": "Admin",
        "Password": "123456",
        "Language_Code": "EN"]


    Alamofire.request("Your API Url", method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if((response.result.value) != nil) {

                let ResultJson = JSON(response.result.value!)

                print("ResultJson==",ResultJson)

                let UserCount = ResultJson["users"].count

                if UserCount > 0 {

                    // Do with your above code

                    let Email =  ResultJson["users"]["email"].stringValue
                    let id =  ResultJson["users"]["id"].intValue
                    let money =  ResultJson["users"]["money"].intValue
                    let password =  ResultJson["users"]["password"].stringValue
                    let username =  ResultJson["users"]["username"].stringValue
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In both case you are getting `SUCCESS` so you can take `users` as a key and check weather it's containing any element or not like if the username and the password are right you will get

```
(
            {
        email = test;
        id = 1;
        money = 200;
        password = test;
        username = test;
    }
)
```

But if the username and password are wrong you will get empty value for `users` key so in that case you can use

```
if usersDict.count == 0 {

    //username and password are wrong 
} else {

    //username and the password are right
}
```